# How to run multiple timer functions, one after the other in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Lets say I want to run multiple timer functions, one after the other i.e firstly one function runs for 5 mins then after the completion of the first countdown, another timer begins to run for another 2 mins.

I implemented the timer function as below

```
function timer(count) {
    console.log(count)
    let counter = setInterval(() => {
        count = count - 1;
        if (count < 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
        }
        console.log(count)
    }, 1000);
}
```

Then when I call this function twice with different arguments as

```
timer(15);
timer(5);
```

I get the output as

```
15
5
14
4
13
3
11
1
10
0
9
8
.
.
0
```

However my desired output is

```
15
14
.
.
2
1
0
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: You should start the second timer after the first timer has finished. Right now you are starting them at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `timer` function immediately starts a timer. Timers are asynchronous, so when you call it twice, you just start two timers immediately and they run in parallel.

If you want something to happen *after* one is finished, then you have to explicitly say so. You have two options:

## Callback

This is slightly "older" style of dealing with async code. You call a function that will do something later and then give it a function as a parameter for what to do after it's done:

```js
function timer(count, callback = () => {}) { //<-- take callback
 //if callback is not supplied, it's going to be an empty function
       
    console.log(count)
    let counter = setInterval(() => {
        count = count - 1;
        if (count < 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            callback(); //<-- run callback after this timer is finished
            return;
        }
        console.log(count)
    }, 1000);
}

//run a timer for 15 then a timer for 5
timer(15, () => timer(5));
```

This *works* but excessive use of callbacks can lead to what's known as [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). The example here is prone to it as well, for example if you want to run a timer for 5, then for 4, then for 3, then for 2, then for 1, you end up with this:

```
timer(5, 
  () => timer(4, 
    () => timer(3, 
      () => timer(2, 
        () => timer(1)
      )
    ) 
  )
);
```

Or in one line (for fun):

```
timer(5, () => timer(4, () => timer(3, () => timer(2, () => timer(1)))));
```

## Promise

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are a newer way of handling async operations and help keep the code cleaner.

```js
function timer(count) {
  console.log(count)

  return new Promise(resolve => { //return a Promise
    let counter = setInterval(() => {
      count = count - 1;
      if (count < 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        resolve(); //it is resolved when the count finishes
        return;
      }
      console.log(count)
    }, 1000);
  });
}

//run a timer for 15 then a timer for 5
timer(15)
  .then(() => timer(5));
```

One thing Promises help out is the callback hell, now if you want to run a timer for 5, then for 4, then for 3, then for 2, then for 1, you get a much more reasonable code:

```
timer(5)
  .then(() => timer(4))
  .then(() => timer(3))
  .then(() => timer(2))
  .then(() => timer(1));
```

No more nesting.

### async/await

This is actually Promises again. But wearing a disguise. If a function returns a Promise, you can `await` it which waits until the Promise is resolved, then executes the next lines of code. You can only use `await` inside an `async` function, however since `await` actually transforms your code to a Promise behind the scenes. Functionally, there is little difference but you can just structure your code differently:

```js
function timer(count) {
  console.log(count)

  return new Promise(resolve => { //return a Promise
    let counter = setInterval(() => {
      count = count - 1;
      if (count < 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        resolve(); //it is resolved when the count finishes
        return;
      }
      console.log(count)
    }, 1000);
  });
}

//run a timer for 15 then a timer for 5
async function main() { //you can only use `await` in async funcions 
  await timer(15);
  await timer(5);
}
/* the above will actually be transformed behind the scenes into:
timer(15)
  .then(() => timer(5));
*/

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the first call to finish before doing the second call. An easy way to do that is by wrapping the `setInterval` call with a `Promise` and call `resolve` when the counter reaches 0.

### Using Promise (ES6 but runs on most browsers, needs Polyfill for IE)

```js
timer(15).then(timer.bind(0, 5));

function timer(count) {
  console.log(count);
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
      count = count - 1;
      if (count < 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        resolve();
        return;
      }
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

### Using `async` and `await` (ES7)

```js
(async function() {
  await timer(15);
  await timer(5);
})();

async function timer(count) {
  console.log(count);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      count = count - 1;
      if (count < 0) return resolve(), clearInterval(intervalID);
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: "*(ES6 only)*" tiny correction - `await` was not in ES6 but was finalised in `ES2017`. I'm not sure if OP cares that much - they are already using arrow functions, so ES6 seems to be fine.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for the note (usually confuse es6 and es6+ since neither are fully supported by modern browsers). Updated my answer.

Comment: `await` is probably the only ES >6 feature I can name confidently. I only remember it because when ES6 came out `async/await` was getting quite a lot of popularity...and it wasn't in ES6. Well, half of it. The *useful* half. IIRC, most, if not all, places that supported `async` also supported `await` but the spec was held up for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with async stuff in modern javascript are promises and `async/await`. But because there is no default way to `wait` we need to write it ourself. Thats pretty simple tho:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Now we can use this to write your `timer` with `async/await` and make it return a `Promise`:

```
async function timer(count) {
    for(let i = count; i > 0; i--) {
        await wait(1000);
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

And not its easy to use `timer` multiple times in an async function:

```
await timer(15);
await timer(5);
```

---

So the full code is:

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function timer(count) {
    for(let i = count; i > 0; i--) {
        await wait(1000);
        console.log(i);
    }
}

async function multipleTimers() {
    await timer(15);
    await timer(5);
}

multipleTimers();
```

Comment: I don't see why you would fully rewrite the timer function. The interval was already performing the role of your wait. I think you increased the complexity a little bit.

Comment: I stronly disagree. While you're right that the performance will decrease, this is irrelevant when waiting a second anyway. However the rewrite is far simpler to read then the original with an additional `return new Promise(resolve =>` and also more resilient to errors when doing more then a simple `console.log`. The necessary `try/catch` and `reject()` call is easy to forget when adding logic.

Comment: But by adding a timeout for each wait, you also lost a lot of precision. While the setInterval will trigger precisely each 1000ms (not necessarily, but self consciously enough to self correct after each loop), calling sequential timeouts may cause them to be slightly delayed after each other, which can add up with bigger number of loops.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you wanted the second `timer` function to be executed only when all the intervals from the first one are completed. This is absolutely not what you implemented. As it is, the first function is called, which sets the interval, and finishes. The main code is not interrupted by the setting of the interval, so it will simply keep executing, calling the second `timer` function.

According with your desired output, you will certainly need an async function, to know when the first interval is done executing. Here is what you can try:

```
function timer(count) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       console.log(count)
        let counter = setInterval(() => {
            count = count - 1;
            if (count < 0) {
                clearInterval(counter);
                resolve();
                return;
            }
            console.log(count)
        }, 1000);
    }
}

timer(15).then(() => {
    timer(5);
});
```

If you are already in an async function, the last bit can also be written as:

```
await timer(15);
timer(5);
```

You should give a read about [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). It's really worth it.